# C# LINQ Remove multiple objects from a list in single execution

Tags: c#, .net, linq, interface

It seems quite similar, but my question is quite different. I have a list which consists of objects which are implementation of different interface. 
I want to delete a particular type's objects, but after passing another criteria. A sample code is given below.

```
 // remove the not required parameters 
foreach (EndPoint endPoint in endPoints)
{                 
    var maps = endPoint.EndPointParameters
        .Where(x => x is IEndPointParamMapCustom)
        .Cast<IEndPointParamMapCustom>()
        .Where(x => !x.IsActive)
        .ToList();

    foreach (var custom in maps)
    {
        endPoint.EndPointParameters.Remove(custom);
    }
}
```

I want to remove the below foreach loop and remove the objects in the above single LINQ query. Is it possible? 
Thanks.

Comment: In general LINQ should never be used to modify objects but to query them

Comment: I guess it´s possible but the question is: why? YOur code is pretty straitforward, easy to understand and thus maintainable. Introducing any further LINQ will just mess your code up.

Comment: Given that the `Q` in LINQ stands for ***Query***, you'll never perform this "single query" mutation without abusing the intent of LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `EndPointParameters` is a `List<T>` ("remove multiple objects from a *list*") you can try `RemoveAll` instead of *Linq*:

```
// Remove the not required parameters 
foreach (EndPoint endPoint in endPoints)
{ 
    // Remove all items from EndPointParameters that both
    //   1. Implement IEndPointParamMapCustom 
    //   2. Not IsActive 
    endPoint
      .EndPointParameters                
      .RemoveAll(item => (item as IEndPointParamMapCustom)?.IsActive == false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `RemoveRange` function 
`endPoint.endPointParameters.RemoveRange(maps)`

Comment: thanks.  but I asked to merge the both statements into one.  not just to use removerange.

Comment: the syntax you provided gives a build error. it seems you didn't even check the code by yourself.